# Correct way to create custom "Todo Items"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper, resharper-9.0

Resharper allows me to create custom "To-do Items" under ***Options -> Tools -> To-do Items***. These todo items include a color value.

But there is also a color found under ***Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Display Items -> Resharper Todo Item***.

My todo items will only use the latter color (the VS one); the color chosen in the To-do Items dialog does nothing. Even if I set the ***Resharper Todo Item*** color to ***Default*** or ***Automatic***, it does not use the one set for the specific todo item.

Why is there two apparently contradicting colors for this, and how do I get the one from the To-do Items dialog to be used instead?

Comment: *"Correct way to create custom “TODO” items?"* Usually the "correct" way is to create a work item in your versioning system of choice, TODO's in code really are a horrible way to track work.

Comment: @RonBeyer They are just named "Todo Items". They are not necessarily todos, they are just a way of color coding comments using some kind of name. A todo comment is only one example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in ReSharper - any custom colour for todo items is ignored, and it only uses the setting in Visual Studio's Fonts and Colours settings page. I've opened an issue you can use to vote and track: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-445641